# Почему текстовый редактор Sublime Text не видит следующие переменные?

Tags: вёрстка, sass, sublime-text

[[image: [1]]

**_header.sass**

```
.header
    &-contacts
     display: flex
     justify-content: flex-end
     &__phone
      font-size: 22px
     &__button
      font-size: 14px
      font-weight: 400
      color: $text-color-light
```

Comment: 1) давно редактор Sublime Text не обновляли 2) не выбрали syntax sass ? 3) может требуется плагин установить для sass 4) перечислил возможные причины но это не точно ...

Comment: @Leks 1) Обновляла 2) Выбрала 3) Плагин тоже установлен

Comment: У меня подключена gulp + sass. До переменных все правильно конвертировал.

Comment: @Leks Я обновила редактор и все исправилось(хотя недавно я обновила редактор). Но синтаксис переменных в файле _variables.sass не правильный.

Comment: Я заметила что сначала надо подключить переменные(вот так import 'variables' import 'header'). Когда их после подключаю(типа вот так import 'header' import 'variables')
 не компилируется файл, gulp выдает ошибку. Наверное недавно тоже проблема в этом была. P.S.знак @ не написала в комменте перед import, потому что не разрешается.

Comment: @Leks Спасибо вам, помогли.